# What is the most efficient way to iterate over a set with some conditions?

Tags: python, optimization, set, conditional-statements, list-comprehension

I have a simulation set up where I have a set of tuples. Each tuple contains the indices for a specific position in my numpy array.

At some point I have to iterate through this set of tuples to apply 3 conditions to filter out indices, and then I pick a random tuple. My code is as following:

```
def fillASRS(arr, fillLevel):
    toFill = round(float(vol*(fillLevel/100)))
    shape = arr.shape
    arr_1D = arr.reshape(-1)
    inds = np.random.choice(arr_1D.size, toFill, replace = False)
    arr_1D[inds] = 1
    arr_3D = np.array(arr_1D.reshape(shape))
    arr_3D.astype(np.int8)
    return arr_3D

warehouse = np.zeros([ASdepth,ASheight,ASlength])
warehouse = warehouse.astype(np.int8)
fillASRS(warehouse, z)
zeros = set(map(tuple,np.argwhere(warehouse==0)))
```

This is executed at the beginning, my 3D numpy array is created and filled with 1s and 0s and my set of positions where the array is 0 is created.

Afterwards my code looks like this:

```
def reloc_findSpot(coords):
    new_arr=[ele for ele in zeros if ele[0]==coords[0] if 1 not in warehouse[:ele[0],ele[1],ele[2]] if (warehouse[-(ASdepth-1-ele[0]):,ele[1],ele[2]] == warehouse[-(ASdepth-1-coords[0]):,coords[1],coords[2]]).all]
    random_idx=np.random.randint(len(new_arr))
    relocSpot = new_arr[random_idx]
    return relocSpot
```

Here I iterate through my set applying the three conditions, and then I pick a random tuple out of the existing remaining ones. This condition, as you can see, is dependent on coords, which is a different tuple each time this function is called.

My program takes a really long time to execute (I run 1000-100000 iterations depending on the test), and when I profiled it, it told me that most of my execution time is spent in this list comprehension as seen here:

```
   Ordered by: cumulative time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.038    0.038   10.004   10.004 c:\Users\Eduardo\Desktop\Thesis Docs\SIMULATION\Simulation_Test.py:247(start)
      526    0.009    0.000    9.662    0.018 c:\Users\Eduardo\Desktop\Thesis Docs\SIMULATION\Simulation_Test.py:232(relocation)
      526    0.003    0.000    9.652    0.018 c:\Users\Eduardo\Desktop\Thesis Docs\SIMULATION\Simulation_Test.py:374(reloc_findSpot)
      526    9.643    0.018    9.643    0.018 c:\Users\Eduardo\Desktop\Thesis Docs\SIMULATION\Simulation_Test.py:375(<listcomp>)
      500    0.013    0.000    5.330    0.011 c:\Users\Eduardo\Desktop\Thesis Docs\SIMULATION\Simulation_Test.py:140(retrieval_Iteration)
      500    0.012    0.000    4.627    0.009 c:\Users\Eduardo\Desktop\Thesis Docs\SIMULATION\Simulation_Test.py:108(storage_Iteration)
     1000    0.051    0.000    0.269    0.000 c:\Users\Eduardo\Desktop\Thesis Docs\SIMULATION\Simulation_Test.py:363(rnd_findSpot)
     1000    0.187    0.000    0.204    0.000 C:\Users\Eduardo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\random.py:315(sample)
```

My understanding is that list comprehension is basically executing a for loop, so I figure turning this into a for loop is useless.
My question is, is there a way to more efficiently iterate through a set, and filter out tuples based on 3 conditions?

Some extra info if needed:

- My warehouse is a 3D numpy array with 1s and 0s
- The set of tuples gets updated with the locations of the 0s and the 1s as these values change throughout my simulation.
- The third condition in my list comprehension gives me close enough results, but I am not very confident in my understanding of comparing slices of data.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you try using `np.fromiter((x for x in arr if condition), dtype=arr.dtype)`? I believe this is much faster than doing `[x for x in arr if condition]`. Please try it and comment if works

Comment: If the list comprehension is where you need help, I suggest that you provide some minimal sample input data that can be used as input for the list comprehension. We can then work on an alternative to the list comprehension, feed the same input to the alternative, and finally, check if the result is identical to the list produced by the list comprehension. That's the only way to go forward, because outside of your `reloc_findSpot()` we will not have clue what exactly was the list produced by your list comprehension.

Comment: To emphasize, note that I said *minimal* sample input data, where your width, height, and length are all small.

Comment: I think I've made some progress working on your list comprehension, but one thing puzzles me. Towards the end of your list comprehension, there's an `all`. Was this intended to be an invocation of `np.ndarray.all()`? If so, why is it just `all` and not `all()` ?

Comment: I believe that `all` is a programming mistake and needs to be corrected to `all()`. But that is sure to alter the results. You've mentioned that you currently have "close enough results", but I believe these may become irrelevant after this correction. Which means that you need to re-verify and re-confirm the **correctness**, before addressing speed issue. Option(A) Do you want to drop the 3rd condition and optimize the list comprehension for speed?, OR Option(B) Pause here and come back after verifying that the 3rd condition, after the correction, is still producing "close enough results"?

Comment: Thank you all so much for your help so far! @FlavioMoraes I will try this out tomorrow and report back, but the list comprehension I am using is being applied to a set, so I don't know if it will allow me to use np functions against it. Tomorrow I will try to change this set into a numpy array and use your suggestion, thank you very much!

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment @fountainhead. I corrected the all to all() and the results are actually more or less the same (I should be getting a probability of 0.41 in two different results, and my results before and after that change are still around 0.41 +/- 0.2 which is close enough. That all() is due to the fact that I am comparing two slices of data, and it outputs an array of booleans. I am specifying that I want all of them to be true.

Comment: @fountainhead This list comprehension is only contained within `reloc_findSpot()` and is used to pick a tuple within that list that will fulfill those three conditions. Getting rid of any of the conditions will make my model not work. I am thinking of rather than filtering the whole list, finding the first tuple that satisfies all three conditions. I think my results won't change much, but it is not an ideal solution.

Comment: @Edu31416 -- Before correcting `all`  to `all()`, print the output of the list comprehension alone (not the output of `reloc_findSpot()`. Then, after the correction, again print the output of the list comprehension. The two list comprehensions will be very DIFFERENT. The number of elements in the resulting lists will also be different before and after.

Comment: On checking again, I find that `new_arr` is the same before and after correcting `all` to `all()`, much to my surprise. I will look into this further. Until then, pls ignore (some of) my earlier comments on the difference in output.

Comment: @Edu31416 - I have posted an answer. Please check and let me know. It's still a list comprehension, but is likely to have much fewer iterations. (For getting fully rid of the list comprehension, it was easy to find non-loop alternatives for the first and third condition, but I was finding it tricky to replace the second condition with non-iterative `numpy` code. Hence this "partial" solution). Let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial solution, which will give moderate improvement in speed.

It still uses the list comprehension but loops over a much smaller range of "tuples". (There will be far fewer iterations)

I mention "tuples" in double-quotes because, in this solution, `zeros` is no longer a `set` of `tuple` objects. Instead, `zeros` is a 2-D `numpy` array of shape `(N,3)` for some large `N`.

## **Details:**

**Step 1 of 3:**

Replace the line `zeros = set(map(tuple,np.argwhere(warehouse==0)))` with this:

```
zeros = np.argwhere(warehouse==0)
```

**Step 2 of 3:**

In `reloc_findSpot()`, before the list comprehension introduce this line:

```
filt_zeros = zeros[zeros[:,0] == coords[0]]
```

**Step 3 of 3:**

In the list comprehension:

1. Replace all `zeros` with `filt_zeros`
2. Remove the first condition

Let me know how it goes with your full-scale dataset.

Comment: Thank you so much! Unfortunately it did not reduce the time much. I have ended up changing the nature of my model a bit, enough that my results are still correct, but my code is much faster.

Answer (score 0):

So in the end my solution was to change my findSpot algorithm. `reloc_findSpot()` no longer creates a list of all possible positions and then picks one. It now returns the first element to match my conditions in the `zeros`set.

This has reduced my runtime from 15 seconds to 0.4 seconds for a 1000 loop run (will have to test efficiency for a much higher number of loops, but this is already a massive improvement). This was achieved with the line
`relocSpot = next(ele for ele in zeros if ele[0]==coords[0] if 1 not in warehouse[:ele[0],ele[1],ele[2]] if (warehouse[-(ASdepth-1-ele[0]):,ele[1],ele[2]] == warehouse[-(ASdepth-1-coords[0]):,coords[1],coords[2]]).all())`

It seems my results were not affected (I guess since sets are not ordered the first item to match conditions is always random anyway).
Thank you everyone for your help!